# Crystal Reports Crosstab Calculation or Dynamic Columns

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have the following data in sql.

```
Date |Customer|DespatchOrder|Value|ApprovedCredit
08/10|Axe     |AGB-01       |50   |200
08/12|Axe     |AGB-02       |75   |200
08/13|Axe     |AGB-03       |80   |200
08/15|Axe     |AGB-04       |10   |200
08/09|Vex     |VSE-01       |50   |150
08/10|Vex     |VSE-02       |60   |150
08/13|Vex     |VSE-03       |40   |150
```

With some manipulation in sql I have managed to display my data in a crosstab in crystal reports like in the examples below:

```
AXE
Date |ApprovedCredit|Total|AGB-01|AGB-02|AGB-03|AGB-04
08/09|200           |0    |0     |0     |0     |0
08/10|200           |50   |50    |0     |0     |0
08/11|200           |50   |50    |0     |0     |0
08/12|200           |125  |50    |75    |0     |0
08/13|200           |205  |50    |75    |80    |0
08/14|200           |205  |50    |75    |80    |0
08/15|200           |215  |50    |75    |80    |10

VEX
Date |ApprovedCredit|Total|VSE-01|VSE-02|VSE-03
08/09|120           |50   |50    |0     |0     
08/10|120           |110  |50    |60    |0     
08/11|120           |110  |50    |60    |0     
08/12|120           |110  |50    |60    |0     
08/13|120           |150  |50    |60    |40    
08/14|120           |150  |50    |60    |40    
08/15|120           |150  |50    |60    |40
```

The problem that I have, I cannot find a way to calculate my overlimit column inside of a crosstab, the over limit is calculated by approvedcredit - Total(Column inside of crosstab)

```
AXE
Date |ApprovedCredit|Total|OverLimit|AGB-01|AGB-02|AGB-03|AGB-04
08/09|200           |0    |0        |0     |0     |0     |0
08/10|200           |50   |0        |50    |0     |0     |0
08/11|200           |50   |0        |50    |0     |0     |0
08/12|200           |125  |0        |50    |75    |0     |0
08/13|200           |205  |5        |50    |75    |80    |0
08/14|200           |205  |5        |50    |75    |80    |0
08/15|200           |215  |15       |50    |75    |80    |10

VEX
Date |ApprovedCredit|Total|OverLimit|VSE-01|VSE-02|VSE-03
08/09|120           |50   |0        |50    |0     |0     
08/10|120           |110  |0        |50    |60    |0     
08/11|120           |110  |0        |50    |60    |0     
08/12|120           |110  |0        |50    |60    |0     
08/13|120           |150  |30       |50    |60    |40    
08/14|120           |150  |30       |50    |60    |40    
08/15|120           |150  |30       |50    |60    |40
```

Please help if you have any idea how to do this, I have tried to create my report without a crosstab, but was not successful with the dynamic column headers. I would like to keep on using the crosstab due to the dynamic nature of this report and sometime there can be more than 10 DespatchOrders but if there is no way to do this using a cross tab please help with alternative.

I found away to create the over limit column inside of Crystal Report using a Calculated Member with a value formula

```
ApprovedCredit - GridValueAt(CurrentRowIndex, 0 ,0)
```

The GridValueAt function is now supported by crystal reports xi neither is a calculated member. Just another brick wall

Answer (score 0):

If you can calculate your overlimit value upstream, the crosstab will be easy.  If you can't do that, you'll need to base your crosstab columns and summarized fields value on a formula instead of actual fields from your datasource.  In your formula, you return the field value you want to appear in most of the columns, and calculate the value to display in the overlimit column.